# How to update a row using old values without a query in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to update certain cells of db table. I have a function that updates certain value, here it is:

```
public final int updateBpm(long millisOfDay, float bpmValue, int trngTime, int id) {
mDb.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_BPM_STAT +
  " SET " + BPM_COLUMN + " = (" + BPM_COLUMN + " * " + TIME_COLUMN + " + "
  + bpmValue + " * " + trngTime + ") / (" + TIME_COLUMN + " + " + trngTime + "),"
  + TIME_COLUMN + " = " + TIME_COLUMN + " + " + trngTime + ", "
 + " WHERE " + DATE_COLUMN + " = " + millisOfDay +
  " AND " + ID_COLUMN + " = " + id);
// here if affected rows == 0, I should insert this value
}
```

I've looked at `db.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`. It returns affected rows, but how can I update certain cell using another cells of the same row, without replacing it?

```
final ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
updateValues.put(BPM_COLUMN, ..); // I don't need replace it, I need to use old data from the table to construct a new one
updateValues.put(TIME_COLUMN, ..);
mDb.update(STAT_TABLE, updateValues, ID_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

How can I do it using update method, but without query before it?

Comment: Unclear. Also note that an `UPDATE` is a **command**, not a **query**. Only `SELECT` is called a **query**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update()` method supports only literal valued.
To be able to use old values for computations, you have to keep using `execSQL()`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that it's impossible to get affected rows from "execSQL" method. From another hand, it's impossible to update old values using "update" method as well.